# Xbox 360 and Xbox 360 slim graphics difference

Tags: xbox-360

Is there any graphics difference between the Xbox 360 and Xbox 360 slim?
I have a Xbox 360 and I'm wondering if I should upgrade?

Comment: Did you actually do any research?  Literally the first post in my Google search outlines the differences.

Answer (score 1):

There are no graphics differences between both versions of these Xbox 360s.  They both use the [same GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_technical_specifications#Graphics_processing_unit) and output the same.

As pointed out in the comments, unless you have a 360 without an HDMI (it would have to be a very early 360 from 2005-2007) you won't see a difference.  If you are already using HDMI, then you are already seeing the best graphics possible from a 360.

Really if you're looking to upgrade, you need to move up to an Xbox One.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that depending on the age of the Xbox 360, it may not come with an HDMI port, requiring component/AV cables, where there is a noticable lack of quality. Slims, afaik, have HDMI.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf hmm I never knew that. It looks like [starting after 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360#AV_output) they introduced an HDMI port.  That would be right about when I got my 360 which had an HDMI.

Comment: Unfortunately, my sister and I received one a bit earlier; it has a giant proprietary video port with AV male on the other end.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf yup I remember those.  My Xbox had that along side an HDMI port.  I remember it had a switch to switch between 480p and 720p.

Comment: I remember having to buy a set of component cables to get any HD at all.  I can't believe they still sell so many 360s.

Comment: Note: While you *can* play Xbox 360 games on a Xbox One, backwards compatibility is achieved through emulation. While the graphics wouldn't change, some games may suffer from worse framerate (while others may benefit from better ones). Just a thing to keep in mind, though I'd still recommend going for an XBO instead of another 360.

Comment: @Nolonar *cough* Assassin's Creed *cough*